# User registeration as inactive and activation via OTP

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Following are the steps for authentication flow:

1. User does the registeration by entering his details and he will be
   sent an OTP to his mail.
2. At this time user details stored to
   mongoDB.
3. Usually after validation of OTP, a user can login to
   application. But in my case before validating OTP, user can login to
   application.

How to solve this please help me. Some of my code shown below.

### model.js

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
  mobile: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
});
```

### controller.js

```
vm.submitPost =  function(userData){
        $http({
            url: 'http://192.168.2.8:7200/api/pages/auth/register',
            method: 'POST',
            data: userData
        }).then(function(res) {
            if(res.data.success){
                $location.path('/pages/auth/otp');
            } else {
                alert('Please fill all credentials');
            }
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error.data);
        });
    };
```

### node.js

```
router.post('/pages/auth/register',function(req, res, next){
    var user = new User({
        name: req.body.username,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        mobile: req.body.mobile,
    });

    var secret = "mysecretkey";
    var code = otp.generate(secret);    
    var insertOtp = function(db, callback) {
        db.collection('otp').createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 10 } );
        db.collection('otp').insertOne( {
                "createdAt": new Date(),
                "generatedOtp": code,
                "logEvent": 2,
                "logMessage": "Success!"
           }, function(err, result) {
                assert.equal(err, null);
                callback(result);
          });
    };

    MongoClient.connect(config.database, function(err, db) {
      assert.equal(null, err);
        insertOtp(db, function(err,docs) {
          db.close();
      });
    });

    var mailOptions={
        to : req.body.email,
        subject : 'OTP',
        text : "Your One-Time Password is "+code
    }
    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.end("error");
        }else{
            res.end("sent");
        }
    });

    user.save(function(err){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
            return;
        }
        res.json({
            success:true,
            message: 'User has been created!'
        });
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add active attribute to your schema with  default value false when user has validated through OTP, then set this attribute to true and allow user to login if this attribute is true.

```js
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  email: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
  mobile: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true, select: true},
  active:{ type: 'Boolean',
        default: false}
});
```